# Copy Resources to disk

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

First attempt at a VB.NET application. I am trying to create an application to copy standard configurations for an application then customize certain settings for that user. I have most of the application working fine but I'm having an issue with resource files.

Because the number of files may change I'm using a sub-folder for my resources. I have the files set to content and always copy. I can get the following code to work in debug but it seems I'm not doing it properly for build.

```
For Each strFile In Directory.GetFiles(".\Files")

        If Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileName(strFile)) = ".vbs" Then
            strDestination = strDataPath & "Scripts\"
        Else
            strDestination = strDataPath
        End If
        If Not Directory.Exists(strDestination) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strDestination)
        End If

        If My.Settings.chkForceOverwrite = True Then
            Try
                File.Copy(strFile, strDestination & Path.GetFileName(strFile), True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                File.Copy(strFile, strDestination & Path.GetFileName(strFile), False)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    Next
```

I have attempted several ways of copying the data but I can find nothing compatible, like the following.

```
Dim strFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFile)
File.WriteAllBytes(strDestination & strFile, My.Resources.strFileName, True)
```

Can someone point me in the proper and correct direction to do this? Currently the file types are 1 .vbs and 1 .exe.config file but I may need to add different file types in the future.

Comment: what kind of result from that code ?

Comment: Are you referring to the File.WriteAllBytes?  'strFileName' is not a member of 'Resources'

Comment: No, the first code .. is it make unwanted result ?

Comment: When I run it as debug it works fine, I'm guessing because the Files folder is created. But when I build it out and move the .exe I receive: "could not find part of the path 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\Files'.

Comment: I'd prefer not to need to put the folder on the desktop first, I'd have to then do cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About this code ..

```
File.WriteAllBytes(strDestination & strFile, My.Resources.strFileName, True)
```

If you access some special folder such as Desktop and retrieve from app resource , you make it like this

```
File.WriteAllBytes(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\" & strFile, My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(strFileName), True)
```

Comment: I tried to use File.WriteAllBytes in place of the copy, because it looks like the right way to accomplish this. but I get "'strFileName' is not a member of 'Resources'" as an error. How can I fix that or get around it?

Comment: Looks good, after I take off the ",True" it no longer has an error. How would I fix the array of files to look at the \Files in the resources?      For Each strFile In Directory.GetFiles(".\Files")  Would that become      For Each strFile InMy.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet("\Files)  or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is this line `For Each strFile In Directory.GetFiles(".\Files")`

.\Files is referring to a relative path that doesn't exist when you move the .exe.

Comment: It is a relative path inside the .exe as a saved resource. I just can't find a single answer on how to reliably access the resources.